# How to send email invitation to my LinkedIn connects?

Tags: openid, linkedin-api

Unlike OpenID provider, LinKedIn API does not return the email ID to the RP.

So, without the email ID, how can send an email to the user?
Furthermore, how to send email invitation to my LinkedIn connects to join my web site programmatically?

Comment: Hello, take a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56461050/2008488), maybe I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

The [Invitation API](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1012) for LinkedIn does not support invitations in this manner - the invitations are meant to be sent to non-connected LinkedIn members, inviting them to become connections with the person sending the invitation.

If you want to send an email message to your connections via the [Messaging API](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1044), you would not necessarily need to know their email address.  As you are already connected, you would simply pull their Member ID, and construct the XML as described in the linked document.

In terms of sending a message to all the authorized user's connections to also authorize the website, you must be sure that you follow the guidelines, in terms of having the user initiate the mailing (opt-in), review the exact message being sent, etc.  Also, messaging between connections is subject to [throttle limits](http://developer.linkedin.com/docs/DOC-1112), with the current max number of messages a particular user can send per day being 10.

Answer (score 0):

> Open the Page containing all the People whom you wish to send
> invitation:
> Run the below lines in the inspect window:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("artdeco-button__text");



for (var i = 0, len = elements.length; i < len; i++) {
    // send request to all people visible in my network in single click
    if(elements[i].textContent.trim()=="Connect"){elements[i].click()
    elements2 = document.getElementsByClassName("artdeco-button artdeco-button--2 artdeco-button--primary ember-view ml1");
    if(elements2.length>0){
    elements2[0].click()}}
}
```

> There might be some exceptions, due to discrepancy.