# Is it possible to invite Linkedin connections to use my app like Facebook invite?

Tags: facebook, react-native, linkedin-api

I am going to invite Linkedin connections to use my mobile app like [Facebook invite](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites)

I already implemented Facebook invite using Facebook SDK and am not sure if there is any way to invite Linkedin connections to use app.

Comment: Hello, take a look at this [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56461050/2008488), maybe I can help you.